# Android - setArguments to fragment in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I've got an `AppCompatActivity` that has a fragment on it called `TabbedScoreboardFragment`,

Inside that fragment there is a `Tabbar Layout` with `ViewPager`, and the class `SectionsPagerAdapter` that subclass from `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

That is my `SectionsPagerAdapter`

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static final String ME_FRAGMENT_TAG = "meFragment";
    private static final String FRIENDS_FRAGMENT_TAG = "friendsFragment";

    SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) { super(fm); }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            ScoreboardListFragment friendScoreboardListFragment = (ScoreboardListFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRIENDS_FRAGMENT_TAG);
            if (friendScoreboardListFragment == null) {
                friendScoreboardListFragment = ScoreboardListFragment.newInstance(UserType.friend);
            }
            return friendScoreboardListFragment;
        } else {
            ScoreboardListFragment meScoreboardListFragment = (ScoreboardListFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ME_FRAGMENT_TAG);
            if (meScoreboardListFragment == null) {
                meScoreboardListFragment = ScoreboardListFragment.newInstance(UserType.me);
            }
            return meScoreboardListFragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

The problem starts here:

I'm trying to set the arguments of one of the fragments that I've passed into the `getItem` function, but I can't get the fragment itself, cause it isn't `FragmentTransaction` that has the `replace` function so it could take a tag and with my the tag i could identify the fragment, get it and fire the function `setArguments(Bundle bundle)`

What I've tried to do in `TabbedScoreboardFragment` is:

```
public class TabbedScoreboardFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ME_FRAGMENT_TAG = "meFragment";
    private static final String FRIENDS_FRAGMENT_TAG = "friendsFragment";

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter;

    enum UserType {
         me, friend
    }

    public static TabbedScoreboardFragment newInstance() {
        return new TabbedScoreboardFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabbed_scoreboard, container, false);
        this.viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.container);
        this.sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        this.viewPager.setAdapter(this.sectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        this.viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(this.viewPager));
        this.viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
        ArrayList<MyScores.MyScore> myScores = args.getParcelableArrayList("myScores");
        if (myScores != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.sectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                if (this.sectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(i) instanceof ScoreboardListFragment) {
                    ScoreboardListFragment item = (ScoreboardListFragment) this.sectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(i);
                    Bundle myScoresBundle = new Bundle();
                    myScoresBundle.putParcelableArrayList("myScores", myScores);
                    item.setArguments(myScoresBundle);
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.setArguments(args);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I'm doing `this.sectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(i)`
it always creating a new instance of `ScoreboardListFragment` instead to use and retrieve the existing one.

Thanks for helpers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should not create the create the fragments inside the get item type, because you are recreating the fragment every time the fragments l is on screen. 
What you should do is initiate the adapter with a list of fragments, so then you can have more than two fragments but also the fragments would be just initialize once so the instance is the same as when you initialized them with setArgs.

Comment: Ya, it is really helped me. What I've done is this thing:
https://gist.github.com/asafbaibekov/56f6f3fc0cde337b3b4e48d1f4260143

Comment: `First of all you should not create the create the fragments inside the get item type, because you are recreating the fragment every time the fragments l is on screen`

This statement is not completely true. Sure, calling `getItem()` in isolation will always return new `Fragment`. But does `FragmentPagerAdapter` actually do it? Nope.

Answer (score 0):

Not all the fragments inside are created when you are trying to pass the arguments.
You will have to pass the data in another way or to "ask" for the data when you are creating/showing the fragment